# how to implement MVVM

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I want to use MVVM architecture, I have a view pager which has two fragments. each fragment has a RecyclerView. I created a view model class that extends AndroidViewModel because I needed context to pass to my repository which gets data from an API class that gets data from the server using volley. I expected when a rotate my phone, my ViewModel class doesn't be recalled but based on the logs which I set, it seems when I rotate the phone everything will be starting again.

is it ok? or I have something wrong?

this is my Fragment codes:

```
val viewModel: Fragment1ViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Fragment1ViewModel(Application())::class.java)


    viewModel.getData().observe(this, Observer {
        Log.i("Log","data is Loaded in activity")
    })
```

this is ViewModel Class codes:

```
class Fragment1ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val repository=Repository(application)

fun getData():LiveData<String>{
    Log.i("Log","get data in view model")
    return repository.getListItem()
}
```

}

this is my repository codes:

```
class Repository(private val context: Context) {
companion object {
    private lateinit var serverFetch: ServerFetch
}


private fun setContext() {
    serverFetch = ServerFetch(context)
}


fun getListItem():LiveData<String>{
    setContext()
    return serverFetch.getData()
}
```

}

and this is my ServerFetch class which works as an API for repository:

```
class ServerFetch(private val context: Context) {

private val api: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

private val result = MutableLiveData<String>()


private fun connect() {

    val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, api, Response.Listener {
        Log.i("Log", "ServerFetch Successfully")
        result.value = it

    }, Response.ErrorListener {
        Log.i("Log", "ServerFetch field: ${it.toString()}")
    })

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    queue.add(request)

}


fun  getData(): LiveData<String> {
    connect()
    return result
  }
}
```

and here is my Logs when app will run for the first time:

```
 I/Log: get data in view model
 I/Log: ServerFetch Successfully
 I/Log: data is Loaded in activity
```

and this is my logs when I rotate my phone

```
 I/Log: get data in view model
 I/Log: ServerFetch Successfully
 I/Log: data is Loaded in activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch it at the instantiation of the view model.

ViewModel:

```
class Fragment1ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = Repository(application)
    val data = repository.getListItem()
}
```

Fragment:

```
viewModel.data.observe(this, Observer {
    Log.i("Log","data is Loaded in activity")
})
```